# calling cgi script from other cgi script

Tags: perl, cgi

I found a puzzling behavior using perl cgi for which -- I guess -- there is a perfectly valid explanation but I couldn't find one. 
There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947109/how-do-i-call-perl-cgi-script-from-another-perl-cgi-script) question on stackoverflow, but what it describes seems to fail for me. 
The situation: 
I have two perl cgi scripts. One of them (let's say `script.pl`) can produce a website standalone, but also has a parameter let's call it `BARE` so that it will simply spit out non-formatted information.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

unless ( defined $cgi->param('BARE') ) {
    print $cgi->header, $cgi->start_html,$cgi->h1('Hello World'), $cgi->end_html;
} else {
    print "Bare";
}
```

Now I am trying to call this script with its 'BARE' parameter set as local script (as they are in the same directory) from another script (let's call it `call_my_script.pl`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

use strict;    
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

my $result = qx(./script.pl "BARE=1");

print $cgi->header,$cgi->start_html,$result,$cgi->end_html;
```

When running this script from the command line, I get:

```
> ./call_my_script.pl 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
Bare
</body>
</html>
```

When instead I call the same script via browser it returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US"><head><title>Untitled Document</title>
</head><body>Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US"><head><title>Untitled Document</title>
</head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html></body></html>
```

So despite the fact that I am calling the first script locally using `qx` and I am passing the parameter to get bare formatting, this does not get respected when calling things via browser.

I am probably overlooking something obvious, but I'd be grateful to understand what it is.

Comment: when calling a cgi script the web servers sets up the environment in a specific way. Are you setting up the environment when you call it from another script?

Comment: @Jay I am not doing anything specific to the environment

Comment: @Erik FWIW It would be much better to extract the code you would like to share to a module, and "use" it in the two scripts.

Comment: @TimDeLange that's certainly a valid point and something that I'll look in for the longer term. On the short-term I am forced to get _something_ to work and for that the quick and dirty fix is _much_ easier. Cleaning up -- as unfortunately is often the case -- needs to come later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CGI program normally expects to fetch the parameter values from the environment variable `QUERY_STRING`. Passing parameter values on the command line is a debugging facility, and works only when the program is run from the command prompt

You could try something like this

```
my $result = do {
    local $ENV{QUERY_STRING} = 'BARE=1';
    qx{./script.pl};
};
```

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#DEBUGGING can be turned on and off, isn't limited to an actual command line.  Also you can avoid the shell with https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny

Comment: @optional: I think it would be better to present your information as another solution rather than simply denouncing mine

Comment: why? I down voted because of innacurate comment ... got a msg that I should comment, so I did.  Answer was accepted. If you remove the part "works only..." I'll change my vote. "denounce" is too strong a word. Sometimes I just don't get stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: @optional: I don't care about your vote -- I'm just saying that your comment is useless on its own, and it would be better to contrive a solution

Comment: hmm, you're spreading misinformation about CGI module ... how is it useless to point this out?

Comment: @optional: What do you mean by “got a msg that I should comment”?

Comment: i click the vote button, vote changes, then a popup says "consider adding a comment explaining... " or some such